# ListView dynamically load contents

Tags: android, android-listview

Good day.

What I need:
I need to create a ListView, with custom rows, that will Async-load infos into rows when user scrolls over those rows.
Like -

1. We open layout, there's 5 rows shown.
2. I do async-load for those, for example - load photos.
3. User scrolls down, opens 3 more.
4. I load data for those 3 items.

Question:
 Can anyone please describe a pattern, and elements that I should use to achieve that?

Tried:

- Create a custom View, based on ....Layout (FrameLayout f.e.)
- Put this custom View as a root element in Row's layout
- Override onDraw event of that view.

What I get:

This event is shot every time, when ListView is rendered, and IS SHOT FOR EVERY ITEM from the start...

Any advices would be appreciated, thanks.

Some code

Activity, onResume event.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    tvl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLog);
    LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Ll1);

    LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        ll.add("s"+i);
    }


    CommonCheckRowAdapter cma = new CommonCheckRowAdapter(getApplication(), ll);
    int adapterCount = cma.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < adapterCount; i++) {
        View item = cma.getView(i, null, null);
        lv.addView(item);
    }
}
```

Custom View class body

```
package com.example.testscroll;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CView extends FrameLayout{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    }
    public CView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    }
    public CView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    private void initView(Context context){
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.common_row, this);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //super.onDraw(canvas);
        //Do what you want.
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Showing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Showing " + ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1)).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        MainActivity.tvl.setText(MainActivity.tvl.getText().toString() + " "+ ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1)).getText().toString());
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    }
}
```

Adapter's getView(rest - is by the book)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.common_row, null);
    //Fill
    ((TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText(data.get(position));
    return vi;
}
```

And commoon_row layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.example.testscroll.CView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:text="www"
            android:textSize="50sp" >
        </TextView>
</com.example.testscroll.CView>
```

Comment: the ones i used and which worked for me are: use an asynch loader with a custom cached executor pool to download all stuff when you are on wifi or higher network. When you are on a slower network then use asynch task with a fixed thread pool executor of 3-4 threads triggered on some predicate e.g. view load, or refresh button click and add a scroll listener or a 'load more' footer button for loading more.

Comment: Hmmm, a solution definitely. Thanks. It does what I want (all views are created from-the-start, but loading them is prolonged so that performance is adequate).
I'll wait to see for more elegant solution, but if none will appear - that answers my question. THanks :)

P.S. I thionk I'm just missing something, cus what I need - is just to catch when CustomView is geting shown to a user, and then load data into it... There has to be more-or-less OOB way for that...

Comment: In Listview its tricky. ListView recycles its views based on the ones shown on screen. So if screen can only show 4 views on screen then the listview will only create 4 views and reuse them to show all your list items. This creates synchronization problems in situations when the user scrolls the list while a load is happening in the back.

Comment: This means that while you may be deciding the load pattern in the getView method of the adapter the user may scroll out of the view totally. The best way to deal with listview is not to fight it. Load your data and keep in a list if you have a faster net connection. Else load data only on demand. This doesn't kill the user experience and also prevents synchronization bugs.

Comment: Ok, I do understand that this is a standard WF. But. Why, in that case, I have my onDraw firing for all elements that I add to the List? Logically it would be so that I have onLayout, and probably onInit for all, but onDraw to only 4...
And in that way - I would just use onDraw...

Reason why I go that way (creating items, and populating then with data when needed) is because that approach allows me to minimise amount of work needed, to implement this speed-up for all elements that I have in project.

Comment: lifecycle methods like onDraw, getView and Layout etc will fire for all rows all the time. They are life-cycle methods. They will fire as per their android contract. Its up to you to decide based on some conditions which fire should be allowed to finish and which not. Are you using viewholders? If not then you should. There is a fine balance between performance on app and speed of its data fetch. The way you are doing it will cause a lot of short lived objects on the heap and GC will be too frequent.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String text = "";

public CView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    }
    public CView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    }
    public CView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    private void initView(Context context){
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.common_row, this);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //super.onDraw(canvas);
        //Do what you want.
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Showing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Showing " + ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1)).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        MainActivity.tvl.setText(text);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    }

public void update(){
   text = MainActivity.tvl.getText().toString() + " "+ ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1)).getText().toString();
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.common_row, null);
    //Fill
    ((TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText(data.get(position));
    ((vi)vi).update();
    return vi;
    }
```

Comment: Elegant indeed, but - it doesn't get the job done. I assume that this is because I haven't explained well what I'm trying to achieve...

What I need - is a way, to call my asynctask, when user starts to "see" a row of LinearLayout (in my case, as I had to switch from ListView to LinearLayout)

That's why I was hoping for onDraw, and that's why I'm still wondering if I has misunderstood the docs, where it is said (at least I think it is said so) that onDraw shoots ONLY when View gets visible to user (hits the screen)